# Javascript code in HEAD right before closing Head Tag

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

i want to write some inline JavaScript in  but right before the closing -Tag. I cannot use page.headerData.99999 or so because i need a user function for the output. So i tried to use a viewhelper:

```
$pageRenderer = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(PageRenderer::class);
$pageRenderer->addHeaderData($myStuffHere);
```

But addHeaderData puts my code in the middle of all the header output - just after the meta tags and before all javascripts.

Is there a possibility to put it to the end as last entry of the header block?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how this can be done with pure PHP, but with typoscript you have the option to define your own bodytag:

```
page {
   bodytag (
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
   )
}
```

or more complex with a `bodyTagCObject`:

```
page {
   bodyTagCObject = COA
   bodyTagCObject {
      10 = TEXT
      10.value = https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js
      10.wrap = <script src="|"></script>

      99 = TEXT
      99.data = page:uid
      99.wrap = <body id="page-|">
   }
}
```